# Installing mod_wsgi for Python 3.7 virtualenv

Tags: django, python-3.x, apache, mod-wsgi, centos7

Trying to install mod_wsgi for Python 3.7 to complete setup of Django. But it fails with following error message

```
Collecting mod-wsgi
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9e/37/dd336068ece37c43957aa337f25c59a9a6afa98086e5507908a2d21ab807/mod_wsgi-4.6.4.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: mod-wsgi
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for mod-wsgi ... error
  Complete output from command /home/user/myproject_env/bin/python3.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-9hnl4thc/mod-wsgi/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-a9t55ene --python-tag cp37:

  WARNING: The Python installation you are using does not appear to have
  been installed with a shared library, or in the case of MacOS X, as a
  framework. Where these are not present, the compilation of mod_wsgi may
  fail, or if it does succeed, will result in extra memory being used by
  all processes at run time as a result of the static library needing to
  be loaded in its entirety to every process. It is highly recommended
  that you reinstall the Python installation being used from source code,
  supplying the '--enable-shared' option to the 'configure' script when
  configuring the source code prior to building and installing it.

...

    running build_ext
    building 'mod_wsgi.server.mod_wsgi-py37' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/server

...

    gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I/usr/include/httpd -I/home/user/python/include/python3.7m -c src/server/wsgi_stream.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/server/wsgi_stream.o -I/usr/include/httpd -I. -I/usr/include/apr-1 -DLINUX -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -pthread -I/usr/include/apr-1 -I/usr/include/apr-1
    gcc -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/server/wsgi_thread.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/server/mod_wsgi.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/server/wsgi_buckets.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/server/wsgi_memory.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/server/wsgi_interp.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/server/wsgi_restrict.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/server/wsgi_logger.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/server/wsgi_server.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/server/wsgi_convert.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/server/wsgi_metrics.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/server/wsgi_validate.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/server/wsgi_daemon.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/server/wsgi_apache.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/server/wsgi_stream.o -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py37.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so -L/home/user/python/lib -L/home/user/python/lib/python3.7/config-3.7m-linux -lpython3.7m
    /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/python/lib/libpython3.7m.a(abstract.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against symbol `_Py_NotImplementedStruct' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

...

    /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/python/lib/libpython3.7m.a(getopt.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata.str4.4' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
    /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/python/lib/libpython3.7m.a(parser.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.8' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
    /usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/home/user/myproject_env/bin/python3.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-9hnl4thc/mod-wsgi/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-fxo44dv3/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/user/myproject_env/include/site/python3.7/mod-wsgi" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-9hnl4thc/mod-wsgi/
```

Here is the version information:

```
Apache 2.4.6 
CentOS 7 
Python 3.7.0
Django 2.0.5
```

**Edit:**

```
gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28)
httpd-devel-2.4.6-80.el7.centos.1.x86_64
```

Comment: you have not pasted enough of the error message -- include the full output please.  The useful information is usually right above what you've pasted.

Comment: that aside, purely guessing you're probably missing `apache2-devel` or `gcc`

Comment: gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28)
httpd-devel-2.4.6-80.el7.centos.1.x86_64

Comment: paste the `pip install` command and its full output

Comment: complete error message updated to this link https://github.com/rafayet21/django-mod-wsig-issue/blob/master/mod_wsig_error_message.sh

Comment: pip command was `pip install mod-wsgi`

Comment: I've updated the original post with a snippet of that install log

Answer (score 4):

As is documented in mod_wsgi documentation, your issue is lack of shared library for Python.

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/installation-issues.html#lack-of-python-shared-library
- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/installation-issues.html#mixing-32-bit-and-64-bit-packages

If installing Python from source code yourself, also read:

- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2015/06/installing-custom-python-version-into.html

Ignore that talks about docker. Same issues arise. You have to be careful about selecting configure options.

Answer (score 3):

As the warning from installation indicates, you're attempting to install `mod-wsgi` into a python which does not provide a shared object.

When compiling `python` from source, add the `--enable-shared` flag so that it produces a `libpython#.#.so` shared object which can be linked against

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @Graham Dumpleton for sharing the useful links.

I have installed python from source packages with only --enable-shared, so got error "python: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.6m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory" when tried to install packages via pip3

so did the below steps to make it work.

```
./configure --prefix /usr/local --enable-shared LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib"
make
make install
```

now pip3 install mod-wsgi worked fine.